# MySQL Left join with Like condition like this

Tags: mysql

```
select user_ip  from affi
left join cc on affi.user_ip on  "%cc.auth_ip%"
```

Now the ip field in CC table looks like this : 11.11.11.11:2312 and on Affi table it looks like 11.11.11.11 this.

any ideas? :) thanks in advance

Comment: Hope you need the Dynamic query to achieve your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT
    user_ip
FROM
    affi
LEFT JOIN
    cc
ON
    affi.user_ip LIKE concat(cc.auth_ip,'%')
```

you also could try to use `substr`

Comment: can you give some examples of your tables

Comment: The structure is really basic, 

Tables

Affi:

ID,
User_IP

CC:

ID,
auth_ip

Comment: I think its because in one table the ip is on 

111.111.111.111 format and in another its on 111.111.111.111:34234
same ip, but in one its only ip and in another its with Port attached.

Comment: Yes thats right and because of this I use `like` in my statement. For me the statement is working. Do you get an error or only no results?